# How to integrate Google Cloud Messaging with Cloud Endpoints and Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am trying to build a simple chat messaging app with Android.

I have an Android Studio project with a Cloud Endpoints module. I use this Cloud Endpoints API which is published on my Google App Engine project to communicate with my Cloud SQL database. I can do things like insert rows or delete them. The Cloud SQL database has a table in it called "message" and it is very simple with

```
message
-------
id
sender
receiver
datetime
```

Now I want to integrate push notifications using Google Cloud Messaging.

I saw some tutorials such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ) and it explained sort of how it works.

What I do not get is how I can I should set things up with my Cloud Endpoints and my Cloud SQL database so that whenever I write a new row to "message", a push notification is now sent to whatever user it is being sent to.

I know you can use Parse.com for this but how would I do it/set it up using Android Studio + Cloud Endpoints + Google Cloud Messaging, all of which are published on Google App Engine. i.e. how does Snapchat do it (who use Google App Engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a several ways you could implement this, of the top of my head:

1. you can include a call after you insert messages on your DB to dispatch a message via GCM
2. You can add a "dispatched" field to messages on your DB and have a GAE cron task to pick up un dispatched tasks and send them on a regular basis, marking them as dispatched when the push message goes out.

It really depends on your app context and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think option (1) is the way I want to go. Just wondering if this is the correct way to do it. I really don't want to set up cron tasks, I would like this system to work with the API, but just unsure how people usually do this.

Comment: Both implementations are completely valid, if you are looking for real time notices you should use option 1.